# Google ads rest api create a new sitelink

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm using the [google ads api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-ads-api) package to manipulate data on the Google ads side. I can do the basic operations for campaigns, ad groups and ads. But creating a feed item extension is not working out.

I keep getting the error "Concrete sub type of ExtensionFeedItem is required for this operation." I've set the extension_type attribute, so why is this error showing? Anybody have an example?

```
//https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/rest/reference/rest/v12/SitelinkFeedItem
var feed_item_id = -5
const extensionEntity = [
    {
        entity: 'extension_feed_item',
        operation: 'create',
        resource: {
            resource_name: `customers/${customer_id}/extensionFeedItems/${feed_item_id}`,
            extension_type:enums.ExtensionType.SITELINK, //'Sitelink'
            status: enums.FeedItemSetStatus.ENABLED,
            site_link_feed_item: {
                final_urls: [
                    'https://www.google.com'
                ],
                "link_text": "test",
                "line1": "test line 1",
                "line2": "test line 2",
            },
                "targetedCampaign": `customers/${customer_id}/campaigns/${campaign_id}`,
        }
    }
]
const result2 = await customer.mutateResources(extensionEntity);
```